# Selecting by attribute by specific characters fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, attribute-table, select-by-attribute

I have a field `"HNR_S"`.

It contains values like `"124"`, `"122"`, `"1315"`, `"1465"`, `"15151"`, `"124512642"`.

How can I select more than three numbers?

Comment: You mean values with length greater than 3? and what is the type of column, string or numeric?

Comment: yes, exactly sir and that contains mixed characters like string, special characters and numeric.

Comment: type for a column can be either string or integer, can you confirm in the properties of your layer?

Comment: It have string.

Answer (score 4):

To select records with length greater than a specific value, you can use CHAR_LENGTH(string_exp) expression in "Select by Attribute" ArcMap.

So in your case it should work like this should:

```
 CHAR_LENGTH("HNR_S") > 3
```

Comment: @RakeshReddyPosham Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: sir, i need one more help it is not working in other shape_file could you please suggest why it is not working, i checked that shape file it also like my old shape file only but i'm not understanding.

Comment: can you check the column type in other shapefile? it should be of type string otherwise it won't work

Comment: Possibly because your other shape file has a numeric field, you could also try CAST(HNR_S AS INTEGER) > 100, I've never used this function but it should return 0 if there's invalid characters but would probably return SQL ERROR Invalid..., alternately you could try CHAR_LENGTH(STR(HNR_S)) > 3 to ensure that your numbers are tested as strings.

Comment: i checked that other shape file also in string type only but it is not working.i'm getting error i.e "Function or procedure does not exist"

Comment: can you share a sample of that shapefile?